# Private field object vs private inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Say we have class A. And then I'm writing class B and I need to use class A without exposing class A's public members. So I can use private inheritance, or I can have object of A as a B's private field. If I don't need to add new logic that will manipulate A's fields directly, should I choose private inheritance or adding a private field?

Comment: So there's primarily `public`, `private`, and `protected`. You seem to want `protected` for your case, but I would read up more on access modifiers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Class A's public members without exposing them, do not declare them as public declare them as private. Write class B as a friend class so that it can access A's private data fields.

Answer (score 0):

Google style guide has great discussion why composition (private field) is preferable to inheritance:

https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Inheritance

If you only need functionality, there is no benefit from inheritance. Composition makes intent clear, and makes for easier to read and more maintainable code.